# python requests SSLError

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

While trying to use [the SnapWrap library](https://github.com/Rob--/SnapWrap) I've come across this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'android.clients.google.com' doesn't match either of '*.google.com', '*.android.com', '*.appengine.google.com', '*.cloud.google.com', '*.google-analytics.com', '*.google.ca', '*.google.cl', '*.google.co.in', '*.google.co.jp', '*.google.co.uk', '*.google.com.ar', '*.google.com.au', '*.google.com.br', '*.google.com.co', '*.google.com.mx', '*.google.com.tr', '*.google.com.vn', '*.google.de', '*.google.es', '*.google.fr', '*.google.hu', '*.google.it', '*.google.nl', '*.google.pl', '*.google.pt', '*.googleadapis.com', '*.googleapis.cn', '*.googlecommerce.com', '*.googlevideo.com', '*.gstatic.cn', '*.gstatic.com', '*.gvt1.com', '*.gvt2.com', '*.metric.gstatic.com', '*.urchin.com', '*.url.google.com', '*.youtube-nocookie.com', '*.youtube.com', '*.youtubeeducation.com', '*.ytimg.com', 'android.com', 'g.co', 'goo.gl', 'google-analytics.com', 'google.com', 'googlecommerce.com', 'urchin.com', 'youtu.be', 'youtube.com', 'youtubeeducation.com'
```

Using google I've come across [this answer](http://w3facility.org/question/got-requests-exceptions-sslerror-error-when-running-googleplay-api/) but haven't been able to find `urllib3` in `site-packages`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Well, you should first check if you have a Man-in-the-Middle attack going on and the library is right in refusing the connection. The listed wildcard certificates do not match the given hostname, so the error is okay. If i connect to the site, i get a wildcard certificate for '*.clients.google.com' from Google Internet Authority G2 with a very short validity (only 3 Months), rooted in Global Signs CA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of python does not support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) yet, which is needed to get the proper certificates on sites which have multiple certificates per IP address.

Without SNI you get a certificate for `*.google.com` and others (see the error message), but none of these match the hostname `android.clients.google.com` because the wildcard matches only a single label and `android.clients` are two labels. But with SNI you get the certificate for `*.clients.google.com` which matches the provided hostname and validates fine.

SNI support for python is available with Python 3.x and with Python 2.7.9+, so you need to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using Python 2.7 you need to install **`request`** instead `urllib3`.

```
pip install request
```

Please let me know if still you face the problems.

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for request

Comment: This seems very strange - `request` is a one of the commonly used package. Considering you are using Python 2.7 that's appropriate package.  Could you please let me know system configurations of your machine - such 32bit / 64bit?

Comment: Linux Inspiron 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Robus could you please try with `pip install urllib2` and let me know if it worked for you ?